# Python: Make a dictionary of word count in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tf-idf

I have hard time making a function which count the number keys each keyword appears.

```
adict = 
{0: {'Fantasy': 6, 'Animation': 1, 'Family': 2, 'Action': 6, 'Comedy': 1, 'Adventure': 8},

1: {'Fantasy': 1, 'Drama': 1, 'Adventure': 9, 'Action': 10, 'Thriller': 1, 'Comedy': 1, 'Romance': 1, 'Science_Fiction': 10},

2: {'Fantasy': 8, 'Animation': 2, 'Adventure': 16, 'Thriller': 3, 'Drama': 1, 'Comedy': 1, 'Family': 4, 'Science_Fiction': 11, 'Horror': 1, 'Action': 15},

3: {'Fantasy': 1, 'Adventure': 5, 'Thriller': 4, 'Comedy': 1, 'Science_Fiction': 2, 'Crime': 3, 'Action': 6}, 

4: {'Animation': 2, 'Fantasy': 5, 'Adventure': 5, 'Action': 4, 'Comedy': 1, 'Family': 4, 'Romance': 1}, 

5: {'Fantasy': 1, 'Western': 1, 'Family': 2, 'Adventure': 4, 'Thriller': 3, 'Drama': 3, 'Science_Fiction': 1, 'Romance': 1, 'Crime': 1, 'Animation': 2, 'Action': 5}}
```

As an output, I want a dictionary of each genre like:

```
{'Fantasy': 6 , 'Western': 1, 'Family':4 ...}
```

So, the value is the number of group which contained the key(genre).
For example, 'Fantasy' appeared in all groups(in total 6), and 'Western' appeared only once, so it is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like a simpler solution you could use list comprehension.

First you flatten the dictionary into a list. Then you count how many times each unique element appears in this list.

```
# Flatten the dictionary
genres = [genre for v in adict.values() for genre in v.keys()]

# Count each unique element and build a dictionary
occurs = {g: genres.count(g) for g in set(genres)}

# Result:
# {'Action': 6,
#  'Adventure': 6,
#  'Animation': 4,
#  'Comedy': 5,
#  'Crime': 2,
#  'Drama': 3,
#  'Family': 4,
#  'Fantasy': 6,
#  'Horror': 1,
#  'Romance': 3,
#  'Science_Fiction': 4,
#  'Thriller': 4,
#  'Western': 1}
```

EDIT:
There's also [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), a dict subclass from collections module.

```
from collections import Counter

# Flatten the dictionary (same as before)
genres = [genre for v in adict.values() for genre in v.keys()]

# Create new counter from an iterable
occurs = Counter(genres)

# Result:
# Counter({'Fantasy': 6,
#          'Animation': 4,
#          'Family': 4,
#          'Action': 6,
#          'Comedy': 5,
#          'Adventure': 6,
#          'Drama': 3,
#          'Thriller': 4,
#          'Romance': 3,
#          'Science_Fiction': 4,
#          'Horror': 1,
#          'Crime': 2,
#          'Western': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out.
This is not that elegant but it works anyways.

```
adict = {0: {'Fantasy': 6, 'Animation': 1, 'Family': 2, 'Action': 6, 'Comedy': 1, 'Adventure': 8}, 1: {'Fantasy': 1, 'Drama': 1, 'Adventure': 9, 'Action': 10, 'Thriller': 1, 'Comedy': 1, 'Romance': 1, 'Science_Fiction': 10}, 2: {'Fantasy': 8, 'Animation': 2, 'Adventure': 16, 'Thriller': 3, 'Drama': 1, 'Comedy': 1, 'Family': 4, 'Science_Fiction': 11, 'Horror': 1, 'Action': 15}, 3: {'Fantasy': 1, 'Adventure': 5, 'Thriller': 4, 'Comedy': 1, 'Science_Fiction': 2, 'Crime': 3, 'Action': 6}, 4: {'Animation': 2, 'Fantasy': 5, 'Adventure': 5, 'Action': 4, 'Comedy': 1, 'Family': 4, 'Romance': 1}, 5: {'Fantasy': 1, 'Western': 1, 'Family': 2, 'Adventure': 4, 'Thriller': 3, 'Drama': 3, 'Science_Fiction': 1, 'Romance': 1, 'Crime': 1, 'Animation': 2, 'Action': 5}}


def countdoc(adict):
    convert = {} #to ignore the frequency of each genre and make them into lists
    res = {} #result will be saved
    for k,v in dic.items():
        convert[k] = list(v)

    for k,v in convert.items():
        for i in v:
            res[i] = 0
    for k in res:
        for x,y in convert.items():
            if k in y:
                res[k] += 1
    return res


Output: 
{'Action': 6,
 'Adventure': 6,
 'Animation': 4,
 'Comedy': 5,
 'Crime': 2,
 'Drama': 3,
 'Family': 4,
 'Fantasy': 6,
 'Horror': 1,
 'Romance': 3,
 'Science_Fiction': 4,
 'Thriller': 4,
 'Western': 1}
```